# I have no idea what Phusion Passenger is but it's causing problems with my website

Tags: passenger, phusion

I hope this is the right place to ask, I am not really sure where else to look.

I purchased hosting space and a domain on namecheap several years ago, I built my website using kirby cms and never had any problems - now all of a sudden, as I type my url, I get this message:

"We're sorry, but something went wrong.
The issue has been logged for investigation. Please try again later.

Error ID: f50f422c

Details:
Web application could not be started by the Phusion Passenger application server.

Please read the Passenger log file (search for the Error ID) to find the details of the error.

You can also get a detailed report to appear directly on this page, but for security reasons it is only provided if Phusion Passenger is run with environment set to development and/or with the friendly error pages option set to on."

I have literally no idea what Phusion Passenger is and have for sure never bought it, installed it or used it.

On the troubleshooting page (https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/admin/standalone/troubleshooting/nodejs/) it says I should look at the log file but none of the error logs in my cpanel have reported any problems nor am I able to find the log file they mention (as, as I have said, I am not really sure what passenger is)

Could someone help me understand what's happening? Thank you <3

Comment: After contacting Namecheap support, it turned out that web application was exceeding its resource limit, although this is not indicated anywhere. The issue was partially resolved by requesting Namecheap support to restart my instance of CageFS(when you tell them this, they'll know what it is). Once restarted, your application will be back online(but will go off again when resource limits are exceeded). Sadly Namecheap doesn't help much beyond that. They insist its a problem with the web application and that the developers of the application should know what the cause is.

Comment: Thank you! I contacted Namecheap and they were able to fix it, although they didn't explain it to me like that